Creating bounce spline using geometry nodes
I am trying to replicate Bounce Spline function from Extra Curves Objects using geometry nodes.
How can I achieve that the splines will go around the initial object and not through it?
I think I have to use Raycast node but I don't know how. This is my current setup:

Just to clarify, I would like to achieve this:


I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve : a ball made of rubber bands ? If so, it would be easier to generate circles (like in real life) instead of only one curve. Any reason why you want it to be only one curve ?

I want it to be a procedural spline generated around any object so I can later tweak it or use it for animation.

I can show you how to do this, but I don't know how to solve the intersection problem.
